# Trick mobile keyboard into appearing on web page

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I'm making a Role Playing Game in HTML that responds to character presses, and on mobile browsers I'd like the user to have their keyboard pop up automatically (or as close to it as possible), but I don't want them to have to see the text input field.  Maybe I have to let it be displayed so they can click on it in the first place, but then I'd like to hide it.  I use document.onkeypress / document.onkeydown to handle all of the user typing, which works great on desktop, but makes my game unusable on mobile.

How can I give a mobile user a keyboard?

I've thought maybe let them see the input text field to click on it, but then I z-index it behind my game?  But it seems like I just can't get onkeypress / onkeydown on mobile.

EDIT: This appears to be [a long-standing known limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639).

Comment: Hide the text input, use javascript to get the focus... see if that will make the keyboard appear. If not then maybe have the input hide behind something.... or swap to focus to .click() and see if it reacts the same as the client selecting the text box.... The real question is, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried giving up and just showing a text input, which the mobile browser user can click (and then the keyboard shows up) and start typing, but I could not get key by key values out of it (I think mobile browsers might not support it, waiting for tab or enter to do onchange.

Comment: Okay, clearly mobile browsers support something, I'm sitting here watching Stack Overflow count how many characters I have left, lol.  Time to View Source.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and give people something to work with? It's better than expecting people to write an example for you, maybe show your attempt(s) in the source too as that could be explained to why it isn't functioning as intended... No source = nothing to work with, a reputation of 2.5k... expectation of writing a question are disappointing to say the least.

Comment: Not as easy on mobile to do what you've requested, sorry.

Comment: Well if you don't have the time or patience to display the relevant source code for your question then I don't have the time to further assist you but I wish you luck in finding a solution.

Comment: Here's an example, but see my edit on my question - it appears to be impossible on Chrome on Android.  http://jsfiddle.net/47a7A/4303/

Comment: Here's a workaround that will probably work for me.  On mobile it shows a text area that the user clicks in, and then they can play.  http://jsfiddle.net/47a7A/4329/